# Ansible: [WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm facing an issue while using Ansible 2.9.27 on RHEL 7 to automate my infrastructure, specifically when working with encrypted passwords in my tasks.

When utilizing the `password` option of the `ansible.builtin.user` module to provide an encrypted password,
playbook runs fine but Ansible displays a message

```
[WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed.
```

I generate the encrypted passwords using the `password_hash` filter in Jinja. Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```yaml
- name: Create user with encrypted password
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: user
    password: "{{ mypw | password_hash('sha512', mypw_salt) }}"
```

I store my variables in a separate file. Despite adhering to the correct syntax and guidelines, I haven't been able to resolve this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You 're missing the correct [syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-and-encrypting-strings-and-passwords) `{{ mypw | password_hash('sha512', mypw_salt) }}`

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks I've copy-pasted bad, so I've edited, but the error is the same.

Comment: I've tested same playbook on Fedora 38 (ansible-7.6.0-1.fc38.noarch) and it worked. I think that it's a version issue, but I can't I can't assert it emphatically.

Answer (score 0):

In a setup with RHEL 7.9, Ansible 2.9.27, Python 2.7.5, I am not able to produce an issue. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PASSWORD: TEST

  tasks:

  - name: Configure or update user
    user:
      name: "TestUser"
      password: "{{ PASSWORD | password_hash('sha512', 'salt') }}"
```

results into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Configure or update user] ******
changed: [localhost]
```

**Other Example**

- [How to extend account expiration date of an user via Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76093990/6771046)

---

Just a note ...

> *When utilizing the `password` option of the `ansible.builtin.user` module to provide an encrypted password, playbook runs fine but Ansible displays ...*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PASSWORD: TEST

  tasks:

  - name: Configure or update user
    user:
      name: "TestUser"
      password: "{{ PASSWORD }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Configure or update user] ******
[WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed. ...
```

It is a WARNING message not an ERROR. It means you should provide the password hashed. Furthermore it is not possible to provide an encrypted password (string) without former decryption. See [`user` module – Manage user accounts - Parameter `password`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-password)

> *If provided, set the user’s password to the provided **encrypted hash** (Linux) or plain text password (macOS).*

Please take note about the [fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/).

Comment: your feedback is useful. It's weird why in my case it shows that warning. Your note it's not the case mentiones in my playbook. The password is AFAIK hashed by the jinja filter. Because of that, I don't understand why Ansible complains.